# table.column is not a function in jquery datatabbe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

In jquery datatable  i am getting  error table.column is not a function

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#lsotable').dataTable();

    $("#lsotable thead th").each( function ( i ) {

        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () {
                table.column( i )
                    .search( $(this).val() )
                    .draw();
            } );

        table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>
```

I am getiing the table data from while loops, i want it should be only three columns, how i can do .

Comment: Can you share your full demo code, I mean HTML+Javascript ?

Comment: i am fetching the row data by while query , without select filter it working  fine..

Comment: Check it out this link It will may be help you out: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html also check out the "Comments" tab  in the page for more details. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `dataTable()` to `DataTable()` as shown below.

```
var table = $('#lsotable').DataTable();
```

Comment: i have chnaged it, but it is showing TypeError: table.column is not a function, i am getiign the tables vlaues in while loop..

Comment: @kedgeree, make sure you're including the latest version (1.10+) of jQuery DataTables files available [here](https://datatables.net/download/index).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error "table.column is not a function" but I've just solved.

Old code:

```
const table = $('#my_table');
// table.DataTable({...});
table.DataTable();
$('#my_table thead tr:eq(0) th').each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).html() === $('#my_search_field').val()) {
        table.column(i).search($('#my_search_query').val()).draw();
    }
});
```

New code:

```
const table = $('#my_table').DataTable();
$('#my_table thead tr:eq(0) th').each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).html() === $('#my_search_field').val()) {
        table.column(i).search($('#my_search_query').val()).draw();
    }
});
```

It looks ridiculous but solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using older version of datatable library. I tried with Datatable version 1.10.12 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Those who are struggling with a similar type of problem in datatable version **1.9.*** can have a look on here:
 [Link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/77413/#Comment_77413)